# Function to refactor indents and tabs

Tags: vimscript, indentation, functions

I'm writing a vim function to set hard tabs and refactor indents in a whole file.
This is the function:

```
function RefInd()
    :set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab shiftwidth=4
    gg=G
endfunction
```

And this is the error:

```
Error executing the function RefInd:
Line 2:
E492: Not an editor command: ^Igg=G
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Any help?

Comment: `gg=G` is a normal mode command. Use `normal gg=G`.

Comment: @muru You typically want to use `normal!` to make sure you're not running user-defined mappings.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker of course! My, bad.

Comment: Take a look at `:retab` and `:retab!`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `gg`, `=` and `G` are normal mode commands, as opposed to ex commands which are used within a script.
Writing `normal gg=G` should solve your problem.

As @Carpetsmoker has pointed out in his comment, using `normal!` instead of `normal` might be prudent to avoid running user-defined mappings by accident.

See also [`:help :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal).

Comment: Done. It works.